# Finding mode for every window of size k in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Given an array of size n and k, how do you find the mode for every contiguous subarray of size k?

For example

```
arr = 1 2 2 6 6 1 1 7 
k = 3 
ans = 2 2 6 6 1 1
```

I was thinking of having a hashmap where the key is no and value is frequency, treemap where the key is freq and value is number, and having a queue to remove the first element when the size > k. Here the time complexity is o(nlog(n)). Can we do this in O(1)?.

Comment: What if there are multiple elements with same mode within the same window ?

Comment: Use a bucket queue.

Comment: You can do it in O(n), I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## This can be done in O(n) time

I was intrigued by this problem in part because, as I indicated in the comments, I felt certain that it could be done in `O(n)` time.  I had some time over this past weekend, so I wrote up my solution to this problem.

### Approach: Mode Frequencies

The basic concept is this: the mode of a collection of numbers is the number(s) which occur with the highest frequency within that set.

This means that whenever you add a number to the collection, if the number added was not already one of the mode-values then the frequency of the mode would not change.  So with the collection `(8 9 9)` the mode-values are `{9}` and the mode-frequency is `2`.  If you add say a `5` to this collection (`(8 9 9 5)`) neither the mode-frequency nor the mode-values change.  If instead you add an `8` to the collection (`(8 9 9 8)`) then the mode-values change to `{9, 8}` but the mode-frequency is still unchanged at `2`.  Finally, if you instead added a `9` to the collection (`(8 9 9 9)`), now the mode-frequency goes up by one.

Thus in all cases when you *add* a single number to the collection, the mode-frequency is either unchanged or goes up by only one.  Likewise, when you *remove* a single number from the collection, the mode-frequency is either unchanged or goes down by at most one.  So all incremental changes to the collection result in only two possible new mode-frequencies.  This means that if we had all of the distinct numbers of the collection indexed by their frequencies, then we could always find the new Mode in a constant amount of time (i.e., `O(1)`).

To accomplish this I use a custom data structure ("ModeTracker") that has a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) ("numFreqs") to store the distinct numbers of the collection along with their current frequency in the collection.  This is implemented with a Dictionary<int, int> (I think that this is a Map in Java).  Thus given a number, we can use this to find its current frequency within the collection in O(1).

This data structure also has an array of sets ("freqNums") that given a specific frequency will return all of the numbers that have that frequency in the current collection.

I have included the code for this data structure class below.  Note that this is implemented in C# as I do not know Java well enough to implement it there, but I believe that a Java programmer should have no trouble translating it.

### (pseudo)Code:

```
class ModeTracker
{
    HashSet<int>[] freqNums;        //numbers at each frequency
    Dictionary<int, int> numFreqs;  //frequencies for each number
    int modeFreq_ = 0;              //frequency of the current mode

    public ModeTracker(int maxFrequency)
    {
        freqNums = new HashSet<int>[maxFrequency + 2];
        // populate frequencies, so we dont have to check later
        for (int i=0; i<maxFrequency+1; i++)
        {
            freqNums[i] = new HashSet<int>();
        }

        numFreqs = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    }

    public int Mode { get { return freqNums[modeFreq_].First(); } }

    public void addNumber(int n)
    {
        int newFreq = adjustNumberCount(n, 1);

        // new mode-frequency is one greater or the same 
        if (freqNums[modeFreq_+1].Count > 0) modeFreq_++;
    }

    public void removeNumber(int n)
    {
        int newFreq = adjustNumberCount(n, -1);

        // new mode-frequency is the same or one less
        if (freqNums[modeFreq_].Count == 0)  modeFreq_--;
    }

    int adjustNumberCount(int num, int adjust)
    {
        // make sure we already have this number
        if (!numFreqs.ContainsKey(num))
        {
            // add entries for it
            numFreqs.Add(num, 0);
            freqNums[0].Add(num);
        }

        // now adjust this number's frequency
        int oldFreq = numFreqs[num];
        int newFreq = oldFreq + adjust;
        numFreqs[num] = newFreq;

        // remove old freq for this number and and the new one
        freqNums[oldFreq].Remove(num);
        freqNums[newFreq].Add(num);

        return newFreq;
    }
}
```

Also, below is a small C# function that demonstrates how to use this datastructure to solve the problem originally posed in the question.

```
    int[] ModesOfSubarrays(int[] arr, int subLen)
    {
        ModeTracker tracker = new ModeTracker(subLen);
        int[] modes = new int[arr.Length - subLen + 1];

        for (int i=0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            //add every number into the tracker
            tracker.addNumber(arr[i]);

            if (i >= subLen)
            {
                // remove the number that just rotated out of the window
                tracker.removeNumber(arr[i-subLen]);
            }

            if (i >= subLen - 1)
            {
                // add the new Mode to the output
                modes[i - subLen + 1] = tracker.Mode;
            }
        }

        return modes;
    }
```

I have tested this and it does appear to work correctly for all of my tests.

### Complexity Analysis

Going through the individual steps of the `ModesOfSubarrays()` function:

1. The new ModeTracker object is created in O(n) time or less.
2. The modes[] array is created in O(n) time.
3. The For(..) loops N times:
   . 3a: the addNumber() function takes O(1) time
   . 3b: the removeNumber() function takes O(1) time
   . 3c: getting the new Mode takes O(1) time

So the total time is `O(n) + O(n) + n*(O(1) + O(1) + O(1)) = O(n)`

Please let me know of any questions that you might have about this code.